# how to pass ejs variable to extern js script

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

i have a script on my html page like that:

```
<script>
    let a = <%-JSON.stringify(tags)%>
</script>
```

now I need this variable on my main.js file. But I don't know how I can access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it with `window.a`, **as long as that script tag is above the script tag for `main.js`**, but this requires a different way to set the value at the start.

```html
<script>
  window.a = <%-JSON.stringify(tags)%>;
</script>
```

access in your code like

```js
let foo = a.bar;
```

Comment: that's already the case, unfortunately in my main.js script the a variable stays as not defined.

Comment: In your IDE or when you run the code?

Comment: in my IDE I get the message that the variable a is not defined and when I run the code I got an error that the code can't find the variable

Comment: @kaan46 see updated answer